# Proper way to parse Boolean query string param in node/express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, query-string

I'm waiting for something like the following from the front end

```
....?isUpdated=true
```

so I did something like this in code (as I'm processing only `isUpdated=true`, false need to be ignored)

```
var isUpdated = (req.query.isUpdated === 'true')
```

but it seems bit odd to me.

How to do this in proper way? I mean to parse a Boolean parameter from the query string.

Comment: You're doing everything right.

Comment: wouldn't `Boolean(req.query.isUpdated)` work?

Comment: @Vaulstein No, because `Boolean("false")` will evaluate to true. It is, after all, a valid string ; )

Answer (score 7):

[Docs](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string#parsebooleans) if you are using query-string

```
const queryString = require('query-string');

queryString.parse('foo=true', {parseBooleans: true});
//=> {foo: true}
```

Answer (score 4):

The only thing I would change about your approach is to make it case insensitive:

```
var isUpdated = ((req.query.isUpdated+'').toLowerCase() === 'true')
```

You could make this a utility function as well if you like:

```
function queryParamToBool(value) {
  return ((value+'').toLowerCase() === 'true')
}
var isUpdated = queryParamToBool(req.query.isUpdated)
```

Answer (score 4):

I use this pair of lines:

`let test = (value).toString().trim().toLowerCase();
 let result = !((test === 'false') || (test === '0') || (test === ''));`

Answer (score 3):

Here is my generic solution for getting a query params as a boolean:

```js
const isTrue = Boolean((req.query.myParam || "").replace(/\s*(false|null|undefined|0)\s*/i, ""))
```

It converts the query param into a string which is
then cleaned by suppressing any falsy string.
Any resulting non-empty string will be `true`.

Comment: What would the variation be to leave isTrue undefined for null or undefined strings?

Answer (score 1):

```
var myBoolean = (req.query.myParam === undefined || req.query.myParam.toLowerCase() === 'false' ? false : true)
```

Comment: if myParam is missing myParam.toLowerCase() will fail

Answer (score 1):

My one-liner snippet:

```js
const isTruthy = (val) => val && !['false', '0', ''].includes(val.toString().trim().toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) package

A little code to parse int and booleans

```js
qs.parse(request.querystring, {
      decoder(str, decoder, charset) {
            const strWithoutPlus = str.replace(/\+/g, ' ');
            if (charset === 'iso-8859-1') {
              // unescape never throws, no try...catch needed:
              return strWithoutPlus.replace(/%[0-9a-f]{2}/gi, unescape);
            }

            if (/^(\d+|\d*\.\d+)$/.test(str)) {
              return parseFloat(str)
            }

            const keywords = {
              true: true,
              false: false,
              null: null,
              undefined,
            }
            if (str in keywords) {
              return keywords[str]
            }

            // utf-8
            try {
              return decodeURIComponent(strWithoutPlus);
            } catch (e) {
              return strWithoutPlus;
            }
          }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

With some ideas from previous answers, I ended up using this function to consider undefined values as well

```
const parseBool = (params) => {
 return !(
   params === "false" ||
   params === "0" ||
   params === "" ||
   params === undefined
 );
};
```

Comment: bit weird that `parseBool(undefined)` is false and `parseBool(null)` is true

Comment: yea likely because didn't check for null, hence negating the value

Answer (score 0):

I created a package called `boolean-query-express`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/booleanize-query-express

The difference between it and the other packages is that it treats values as 1 and 0 as booleans and will consider params like isHere, isValid, hasSomething (camelcased).

You can read more about it as it's documented.